# Can't generate EF model correctly with Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL product

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, devart, dotconnect

I have problem when creating Entity Framework model from an existing PostgreSQL database with the Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL product.
This product offer 2 ways of generating EF model from a database and neither seems to work.
 When using an ADO.Net Entity data Model with this Devart provider, the tables list appear empty in the wizard when generating model from database. 
When using the Devart Entity Model, the table list appear correctly in the wizard and model is generated but all navigations properties are missing and all not nullable fields are generated as entity keys.
Anyone has experience with this product and can confirm me if I'm facing bugs or if I'm not using it correctly?
Thanks

Etienne

Comment: It seems that database privileges setting is the problem... But can't find exactly which one...

Comment: We have answered you at our forum http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=25058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it seems that the database user in PostgreSQL I was using to access dabatase from Entity Framework was missing the INHERIT attribute. Without this attribute the user was not inheriting from his group privileges that give him access to database objects...

The behavior differences between the 2 ways of generating EF model is due to the fact that obtaining the metadata in ADO.NET Entity Data Model Wizard is implemented mainly through the 'information_schema', while in Entity Developer it is implemented with 'pg_catalog'.